# Extract domain name without domain extension using function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to extract just domain name in email without domain extension. Example I have email address `katad@hotmail.com` and I need just `hotmail` as output so I can compare with known and accepted domain list.

I tried to use this but it's not output I was hoping for:

```
SUBSTRING(subscribers_email,(CHARINDEX('@',subscribers_email)+1),(CHARINDEX('.',subscribers_email)))
```

2nd example:
I have email as

> d.katana@us.army.mil

, I will need

> us

as domain and when comparing to domain list will result as valid.
3rd example:
I have email as Dra.Katana@us.army.mil, I will need

> us
> and when compared it should be valid, currently it would be null as domain for some reason.

Comment: And what if the email address contains a sub-domain?

Comment: That is certainly great question, I have not come across any emails with sub-domains as of yet, not sure exactly what I should do in that case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(100)='katad@hotmail.com';

SELECT @email AS email
    ,  PARSENAME(REPLACE(@email, '@', '.'), 2) AS domain;
```

**Output**

```
+-------------------+---------+
|       email       | domain  |
+-------------------+---------+
| katad@hotmail.com | hotmail |
+-------------------+---------+
```

**SQL #2**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (email) VALUES 
('katad@hotmail.com'),
('john.m.cappelletti@sub.domain.com'),
('d.katana@us.army.mil'),
('dra.m.katanad@gmail.com'),
('drazen.i.katanic@abc.com');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
    , PARSENAME(SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) + 1, 100), 2) AS domain
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------------+---------+
| ID |               email               | domain  |
+----+-----------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | katad@hotmail.com                 | hotmail |
|  2 | john.m.cappelletti@sub.domain.com | domain  |
|  3 | d.katana@us.army.mil              | army    |
|  4 | dra.m.katanad@gmail.com           | gmail   |
|  5 | drazen.i.katanic@abc.com          | abc     |
+----+-----------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Awesome @Yitzhak Khabinsky, this works, thank you much!

Comment: @DKCroat Careful... edge events like john.m.cappelletti@sub.domain.com would fail

Comment: what would you do in that case @Yitzhak Khabinsky?

Comment: @DKCroat, please edit your original question, and add sample data, and expected output.

Comment: @DKCroat, please try SQL #2.

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky I tried sql # 2, I have email like dra.m.katanad@gmail.com and after using sql #2 domain would be null

Comment: @DKCroat, I extended data sample without touching the `SELECT` statement. Check it out again.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have email like draz.m.katani@gmail.com domain is null, or email draze.katanics@us.army.mil domain is null or drazen.i.katanic@abc.com domain is null etc.

Comment: @DKCroat, I am providing you a minimal reproducible example. You copy it as-is to SSMS, and run it. So far, everything is working as the doctor ordered.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, you have right, I certainly apologize, I was totally looking in some other field, my had and what's in there is not functioning as should :), thank you so much for your help

Comment: @DKCroat, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. It is based on **tokenization**. No need to count for any position of dots, hold intermediate results, `CROSS APPLY`, etc.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky you helped me a lot, thank you so much!

Comment: @DKCroat, Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"

Answer (score 0):

This works for your example, you can add additional `replace` clauses if needed for other top-level names

```
declare @email varchar(100)='katad@hotmail.com'
select Replace(Right(@Email, Len(@Email) - CharIndex('@', @email)),'.com','')
```

Comment: so with this I would get hotmailcom, so I need just hotmail, .com or .net or anything else needs to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that returns the first level domain regardless of any sub-domains:

```
Declare @testData Table (email varchar(100));
 Insert Into @testData (email)
 Values ('katad@hotmail.com'), ('john.m.cappelleti@sub.domain.com'), ('Dra.Katana@us.army.mil'), ('d.katana@us.army.mil');

 Select *
      , domain = substring(td.email, p1.pos, p2.pos - p1.pos)
   From @testData                                               As td
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('@', td.email, 1) + 1))        As p1(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('.', td.email, p1.pos)))       As p2(pos);
```

Results from sample table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You need to start the search from after the `@`**

`CROSS APPLY (VALUES` works wonders for holding intermediate values

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(subscribers_email, v1.atsign, v2.dot - v1.atsign) 
FROM table
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('@', subscribers_email), 0) ) ) v1(atsign)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', subscribers_email, v1.atsign), 0) + 1 ) ) v2(dot)
```